# How to troubleshoot iOS 64bit error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, 64-bit

I have an app which works on 32-bit platforms but throws an error when running on 64-bit devices and simulators.  The code in question is:

```
if ([lastStatus isEqualToString:@"0"]){ //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
                bRetVal = YES;
            }
```

From my class h file:

```
@interface DPXmlHandler : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSString *lastStatus;
    NSString *msg;
    NSMutableArray * locs;
    NSMutableArray *alerts;
    NSMutableArray *mrmMsgs;
    }
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastStatus;
```

I synthesize lastStatus at the top of my .m file.  I am populating the string with a value from an XML file.
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

```
if ([elementName isEqual:@"status"]) {
    //Get attribute value
    @try{
        lastStatus = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"code"];
        msg = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"message"];
    }@catch (NSException *e){
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        msg = e.name;
    }
```

The value is an integer, but I'm failing to understand why I can't store a string of "0" and compare it to @"0". I would appreciate any insight on how to change this.  The values for lastStatus are from roughly -100 to 100.  I can make lastStatus an int or long and use the == operator, but I can't seem to find any guidance on WHY this is a problem.

I checked Apple's [guide on converting apps to 64 bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html), but there's no mention of NSString.

Comment: maybe check `[attributeDict valueForKey:@"code"]` is actually a string, could be something funky happening there

Comment: Let me guess, you doesn't use ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid direct use instance variables use properties instead.

```
if ([elementName isEqual:@"status"]) {
    //Get attribute value
    @try{
        self.lastStatus = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"code"];
        self.msg = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"message"];
    }@catch (NSException *e){
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        self.msg = e.name;
    }
```

Because your's code doesn't retain or copy objects, they got autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

ah, when you said you can make lastStatus and int or a long, it sounds like the value coming back for the key `"code"` is actually an int or a long type, and not an NSString type. the `isEqualToString` is a function of the NSString class, so if you are trying to compare it with a int or a long, it wont work. you can easily convert it by going `@([attributeDict valueForKey:@"code"]).stringValue`

note: @() is an NSNumber, @"" is an NSString

**EDIT**

sorry, you cant actually store ints or longs in a dictionary by themselves, since they need to be NSObject's to be able to be stored, so maybe they are already NSNumbers in there, then you can just use `.stringValue` on the object by itself

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried both solutions and Cy-4AH's got me going faster.  I had a syntax error on @([attributeDict valueForKey:@"code"]).stringValue, so I just went with the quickest path to victory.